# Creating default object from empty value- Code igniter

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

Hello I work on codeigniter and I try to eliminate warnings on my website, I block on:

```
$groups = array();

    if ($bannished_groups) {
        foreach ($bannished_groups as $k => $bannished_group) {
            $groups[$k] = $this->group_model->GetGroupByID($bannished_group->groupid);
            $groups[$k]->db = $bannished_group;
        }
    }
```

I have the error:

> Creating default object from empty value

I tried to declare:

```
$groups[$k]->db = new stdClass();
```

but it does not work and i read the other answers but it does not help me ..

Comment: Is the error on the line `$groups[$k]->db`? Are you 100% that `$this->group_model->GetGroupByID(...);` always returns an object? Even if it gets an invalid ID?

Comment: Sorry and yes the mistake is on the line: $groups[$k]->db = $bannished_group; and yes $this->group_model->GetGroupByID(...); always returns an object.

Comment: `if(is_object($groups[$k])) { $groups[$k]->db = $bannished_group; }` ???

Comment: Oh thanks AbraCadaver!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like the method `$this->group_model->GetGroupByID($bannished_group->groupid);` don't always return an object, even if you think it does :-)

If it returns `null`, an empty string or `false`, you will get that error.

Just check it before you try and use it:

```
foreach ($bannished_groups as $k => $bannished_group) {
    // Get the object
    $obj = $this->group_model->GetGroupByID($bannished_group->groupid);

    if (!is_object($obj)) {
        // It's not an object, skip it and move on to the next
        continue;
    }

    $groups[$k] = $obj;
    $groups[$k]->db = $bannished_group;
}
```

This will make sure that your `$groups`-array only contains objects. If you still want to add it to the array regardless, just store the object directly in `$groups[$k]` instead of in the `$obj`-variable. The logic is the same, though.

Comment: Yet it seems to always return an object, in any case the simple verification makes disappear the warning. Thank you so much!

Comment: ...to the user that made an edit suggestion; why did you try and remove half of the text? Especially the last bit? If you don't think an answer is good, write one yourself instead of trying to modify 80% of someone else's.